# Problema con el marcado y desmarcado de palabras en MongoDB con Node.js y HTML

Tags: base-de-datos

Saludos a la comunidad.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde necesito implementar un sistema de marcado y desmarcado de palabras en un documento HTML. Estoy utilizando MongoDB como base de datos, Node.js para el servidor y HTML para el cliente.

Problema Específico:

He implementado la funcionalidad de marcado y desmarcado de palabras.
Las palabras marcadas se almacenan correctamente en la base de datos MongoDB.
Sin embargo, cuando actualizo la página en el navegador, todas las marcas desaparecen.

**proporciono el código del servidor**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
// Configuración de CORS
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Conexión a MongoDB
const uri = 'mongodb+srv:.........
mongoose.connect()
.then(() => {
console.log('Conexión a MongoDB exitosa');
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error('Error al conectar a MongoDB:', error);
});
// Esquema y Modelo de MongoDB
const palabraSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
palabra: String,
resaltada: Boolean,
});
// Esquema y Modelo de MongoDB
const palabraSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
palabra: String,
resaltada: Boolean,
});
const Palabra = mongoose.model('Palabra', palabraSchema);
// Ruta principal que sirve el archivo HTML y palabras resaltadas
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
// Obtener palabras resaltadas desde la base de datos
const palabrasResaltadas = await Palabra.find({ resaltada: true });
// Enviar las palabras resaltadas al cliente en formato JSON
res.json({ palabrasResaltadas });
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error al obtener palabras resaltadas', error);
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al obtener palabras resaltadas' });
}
});
// Ruta para resaltar palabras (acepta solicitudes POST)
app.post('/resaltar', async (req, res) => {
console.log('Recibida solicitud para resaltar palabras.');
const palabraResaltar = req.body.palabra;
console.log('Palabra a resaltar:', palabraResaltar);
// Guardar la palabra resaltada en la base de datos
const nuevaPalabra = new Palabra({ palabra: palabraResaltar, resaltada: true });
nuevaPalabra.save()
.then(() => {
console.log('Palabra resaltada y guardada en la base de datos:', palabraResaltar);
res.send('Palabra resaltada correctamente');
 })
.catch((error) => {
console.error('Error al resaltar y guardar en la base de datos:', error);
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al resaltar y guardar en la base de datos' });
});
});
// Ruta para desmarcar palabras (acepta solicitudes POST)
app.post('/desmarcar', async (req, res) => {
console.log('Recibida solicitud para desmarcar palabras.');
const palabraDesmarcar = req.body.palabra;
console.log('Palabra a desmarcar:', palabraDesmarcar);
// Eliminar la palabra desmarcada de la base de datos
Palabra.findOneAndDelete({ palabra: palabraDesmarcar })
.then(() => {
console.log('Palabra desmarcada y eliminada de la base de datos:', palabraDesmarcar);
res.send('Palabra desmarcada correctamente');
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error('Error al desmarcar y eliminar de la base de datos:', error);
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al desmarcar y eliminar de la base de datos' });
});
});
// Iniciar el servidor
app.listen(8080, () => {
console.log(`Servidor escuchando en http://localhost:8080`);
});
```

**Código del lado del cliente:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Diccionario</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Texto de ejemplo para resaltar diferentes cosas en un entorno real para ellos utilizaremos diferentes herramientas.</p>
<!-- Agrega un elemento para mostrar mensajes de error -->
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

// Obtener palabras resaltadas desde el servidor
$.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/', function(data) {
if (data && data.palabrasResaltadas) {
var palabrasResaltadas = data.palabrasResaltadas;
palabrasResaltadas.forEach(function(palabraResaltada) {
 marcarTexto(palabraResaltada.palabra);
 });
} else {
console.error('Error al obtener palabras resaltadas desde el servidor');
// Mostrar mensaje de error en la interfaz de usuario
$('#error-message').text('Error al obtener palabras resaltadas desde el servidor');
}
});
// Escuchar el evento clic en el documento
$(document).on('mouseup', function(event) {
var selection = window.getSelection();
var selectedText = selection.toString();
if (selectedText.length > 0) {
marcarTexto(selectedText);
guardarEnBaseDeDatos(selectedText);
}
});
// Función para guardar en la base de datos
function guardarEnBaseDeDatos(texto) {
console.log('Enviando solicitud para resaltar palabra:', texto);
$.post('http://localhost:8080/resaltar', { palabra: texto }, function(response) {
console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', response);
});
// Función para desmarcar en la base de datos
function desmarcarEnBaseDeDatos(texto) {
console.log('Enviando solicitud para desmarcar palabra:', texto);
$.post('http://localhost:8080/desmarcar', { palabra: texto }, function(response) {
console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', response);
// Desmarcar el texto en la interfaz de usuario
desmarcarTexto(texto);
});
}
// Función para desmarcar el texto en la interfaz de usuario
function desmarcarTexto(texto) {
// Encontrar todos los spans que contienen el texto seleccionado
$('span').filter(function() {
return $(this).text() === texto;
}).contents().unwrap();
}
// Aplicar marcado a un texto
function marcarTexto(texto) {
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
var range = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.surroundContents(span);
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Agrego imagen de la consola del navegador**
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

**Pregunta:**
¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender por qué las marcas desaparecen al refrescar la página? ¿Hay alguna estrategia recomendada para mantener el estado de las palabras marcadas en el lado del cliente al utilizar MongoDB?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, consejo o sugerencia que puedan ofrecer. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Cuando carga la pagina, haces la solicitud para obtener los datos de marcado del servidor?

Comment: Hola, la solicitud para obtener los datos de marcado de palabras la realizo después de que la página ha cargado completamente. La solicitud la realizo dentro de la función $(document).ready(), que se ejecuta cuando el DOM (Documento Object Model) ha sido completamente cargado y está listo para ser manipulado.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces la carga inicial de palabras desde el servidor en el forEach llamas a la función marcarTexto() por cada palabra, esta la tenias definida así:

```
function marcarTexto(texto) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  var range = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  range.surroundContents(span);
}
```

El problema es que estas usando `getSelection()` cuando no hay ninguna selección del usuario hecha con el cursor (que es lo que devuelve este método), acabas de cargar la pagina, no hay seleccion que devolver...

En cambio puedes definir otra función que sirva solo para la carga inicial, que tome el texto del párrafo (debes agregarle un id), lo recorra, busque las palabras y las reemplace por un span con una clase que contiene el fondo amarillo:

```
function marcadoInicial(texto) {
  let p = document.getElementById('paragraph')
  let prevContent = p.innerHTML
  console.log(prevContent)
  prevContent = prevContent.replaceAll(texto, `<span class='marked'>${texto}</span>`)
  p.innerHTML = prevContent
}
```

Quedaría así:

```
<body>
  <style>
    .marked {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
  <p id="paragraph">Texto de ejemplo para resaltar diferentes cosas en un entorno real para ellos utilizaremos
    diferentes herramientas.
  </p>

  <!-- Agrega un elemento para mostrar mensajes de error -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Obtener palabras resaltadas desde el servidor
      $.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/', function (data) {
        if (data && data.palabrasResaltadas) {
          var palabrasResaltadas = data.palabrasResaltadas;
          console.log(palabrasResaltadas)
          palabrasResaltadas.forEach(function (palabraResaltada) {
            marcadoInicial(palabraResaltada.palabra);
          });
        } else {
          console.error('Error al obtener palabras resaltadas desde el servidor');
          // Mostrar mensaje de error en la interfaz de usuario
          $('#error-message').text('Error al obtener palabras resaltadas desde el servidor');
        }
      });

      // otras funciones
      // ...

      // nueva funcion:
      function marcadoInicial(texto) {
        let p = document.getElementById('paragraph')
        let prevContent = p.innerHTML
        console.log(prevContent)
        prevContent = prevContent.replaceAll(texto, `<span class='marked'>${texto}</span>`)
        p.innerHTML = prevContent
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```